# Count down and change variable as it happens

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am running a for loop with a break of 1 second between each iteration:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

var text = "";
var i;

// Wait function
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  wait(100)
}

</script>

<script>document.write(text)</script>

</body>
```

Currently, when I open the file in a web browser, the browser window is loading until the for loop has finished and then the results are displayed (five output lines). Is there a way to display the out put "as it happens". With this I mean, I open the page and every second a new line is printed.
Thank you!

Comment: All that wait does is freeze the browser. Learn to use setTimeout/setInterval and do not use document.write.

Comment: Generally you would set a timeout inside the for loop using the iterator as a multiplier for the time delay (`i*1000`). Are you trying to completely pause execution, or simply delay the time between writing things to the page?

Comment: I am trying to delay the time between writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about timeout and interval concepts in Javascript.

Here is code that will do the work. Examine it.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>

function waitAndWrite(num) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let text = "The number is " + num + "<br>";
        document.write(text)
    }, num * 1000)
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    waitAndWrite(i)
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I return the text as a replacement of the previous text line or in other words not add a new line but remove the old one first and then add the new line?

Comment: Also, if I run the script on my computer I all lines are displayed at once.

Comment: Do something like this `<html>
<body>
<script>

const showDiv = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(showDiv)

function waitAndWrite(num) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let text = "The number is " + num + "<br>";
        showDiv.innerHTML = text
    }, num * 1000)
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    waitAndWrite(i)
}

</script>
</body>`

Comment: Thanks! And how do I start this and display the results?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve manually, you can achieve the same with [`WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> The `setTimeout()` method of the *WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope* mixin (and successor to `Window.setTimeout()`) sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => document.write("The number is " + i + "<br>"), 1000 * i); // multiply the delay with i in each iteration
}
```

Comment: That is an easily found dupe

Comment: Thanks! How can I return the text as a replacement of the previous text line or in other words not add a new line but remove the old one first and then add the new line?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your own "wait" function, you could use `setInterval(fn, timeout)` [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) instead.

```js
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(() => {
  i = i + 1;
  if(i === 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  document.write("Your text " + i);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Please prefer `let` and `const` over `var`. `let i = 0; const interval = ...` would be better.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In this case, it is not necessary to use let or const.

Comment: Thanks! How can I return the text as a replacement of the previous text line or in other words not add a new line but remove the old one first and then add the new line?